# Workbook doesn't find macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I created a macro in a workbook which is being used by several persons on their own computers. For some of them, it seems to work fine, but for other a message appears that it can't find the macro on the opened workbook. I already checked the security settings to allow all macros to run but I can't seem to find the problem.

Has any of you had similar problems o know how to solve it?

Comment: I tell you their pcs are haunted!!!! Sell them off as soon as possible or ship them to me in India. :p Ok Jokes apart. The only reason why it works for others and not for some is maybe because in the macros dialog box, under the drop down "Macros in:", you have the wrong workbook selected.

Comment: Are all the other peoples computers using the same cersion of excel as you? Excel 2003 workbooks opened in excel 2010 can have their VBA striped as they don't have the correct file extensions for macro enabled workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why it works for others and not for some is **maybe** because in the macros dialog box, under the drop down "Macros in:", you have the wrong workbook selected. See screenshot.

[image]

The user has to select `This Workbook` if they have your workbook opened. Else they need to select the relevant workbook which has the macros. You can also try and select `All Open Workbooks` to see if your macro is in the list or not.

Answer (score 1):

I did verified that the file had the right extension, that it looked for macros in the right workbook and that macros were enabled. I wasn't able to find a reason for this to happen, though I resolved it by saving it in Excel 97-2003. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for an `.xlsm` file.

[image]

I tried to click `Enable Content` but under `View -> Macros` I could not see anything.

[image]

I then tried to enable the developer tab: `File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Select Developer`. There I selected Visual Basic and now I could see the Macro.

[image]